# Proof Related to the Span in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm working through a proof in my linear algebra textbook, and I think I am
a little stuck. I am trying to prove that if $S$ is a non-empty set of vectors
in a vector space $V$, the the set $W_s$ of all linear combinations of vectors
in $S$ is a subspace of $V$. $W_s$ is often called the span of $S$.

Say for instance that $|S| = n > 0$.
It is pretty easy to show closure under addition for $W_s$, Since if
$$\mathbf{u} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$$
$$\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i v_i$$
for some $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and for $v_1,...,v_n \in  S$,
we can see that
$$\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i + \sum_{i=1}^n b_iv_i
= \sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)v_i,$$
and since the reals are closed under addition, this is another linear
combination of vectors in $S$. Similarly, since the reals are closed under
multiplication, showing that $W_s$ is closed under scalar multiplication is also
quite easy, since by scalar multiplication closure in the reals, for some
$c \in \mathbb{R},$
$$c\mathbf{u} = c \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (ca_i) v_i.$$
However, I am having issues figuring out how to prove if the additive identity
exists in $W_s.$ I am also wondering if there is anything else I need to prove
beyond these three properties, since I have heard that some properties of
subspaces are defined differently in certain books.

Comment: $0=0u$, the first $0$ viewed as the zero vector. Technically there are a number of axioms associated to a vector space, but since subspace inherit vector addition and scalar multiplications from superspaces, the only thing to check is $cu + v$.

Comment: The definition of a subspace is quite standard. Since the set is nonempty, it suffices to show that for any $v_1, v_2 \in W_s$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha v_1 + v_2 \in W_s$, which you have already shown.